# Can you set multiple (different) tags with the same value?

Tags: string, go, struct, go-structtag

For some of my projects, I have had to use the [viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper/) package to use configuration. 
The package requires you to add the `mapstructure:"fieldname"` to identify and set your configuration object's fields correctly, but I have also had to add other tags for other purposes, leading to something looking like the following :

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
    MyField string `mapstructure:"myField" json:"myField" yaml:"myField"`
}
```

As you can see, it is quite redundant for me to write `tag:"myField"` for each of my tag, so I was wondering if there was any way to "bundle" them up and reduce the verbosity, with something like this `mapstructure,json,yaml:"myField"`

Or is it simply not possible and you must specify every tag separately ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Struct tags](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) are arbitrary [string literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#string_lit). Data stored in struct tags may look like whatever you want them to be, but if you don't follow the *conventions*, you'll have to write your own parser / processing logic. If you follow the conventions, you may use [`StructTag.Get()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag.Get) and [`StructTag.Lookup()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag.Lookup) to easily get tag values.

The conventions do not support "merging" multiple tags, so just write them all out.

The *conventions*, quoted from [`reflect.StructTag`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag):

> By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally space-separated key:"value" pairs. Each key is a non-empty string consisting of non-control characters other than space (U+0020 ' '), quote (U+0022 '"'), and colon (U+003A ':'). Each value is quoted using U+0022 '"' characters and Go string literal syntax.

See related question: [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

Comment: Specifically, the conventions described on [`reflect.StructTag`](https://godoc.org/reflect#StructTag).

Comment: @TimCooper Thanks, included.

Comment: You're right, I forgot these were conventions! Thanks for the clear answer !