# How to unmarshal a json string with a hyphen in key to a struct?

Tags: json, go, struct

I have following code which is ok, it will print `Bob`:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    UserName string  // line2
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    var u User
    str := `{"userName":"Bob", "age": 20}` // line1
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &u)
    fmt.Println(u.UserName)
}
```

Unfortunately, in real case, the json string in `line1` is next, which you could see there is a hyphen(`-`) in the key.

```
str := `{"user-Name":"Bob", "age": 20}`
```

And as you all know, to automatically unmarshal the json string, we have to define a member in struct which is the same name of the key in json string, of course need to make it upper case. So I tried to change `line2` to `User-Name string`, but `-` is not valid in `go` variable name. What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use [struct tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) to map struct fields to JSON properties:

```
type User struct {
    UserName string `json:"user-Name"`
    Age      int
}
```

With this it will work, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LQ7QUbP8yrK).