# Parsing JSON using struct

Tags: go

I'm trying to parse JSON using Go. Can anyone tell me why my code is not working as expected?

```
package main
  
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)
type Message struct {
    Name string
    Body string
    Time int64
}

type Person struct {
    M Message
}

func get_content() {

    body := []byte(`{"person":{"Name":"Alice","Body":"Hello","Time":1294706395881547000}}`)

    var data Person
    err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v",data.M.Name)

}

func main() {
    get_content()
}
```

I'm expecting it to print the Name.

[Go playground Code](https://play.golang.org/p/tzY5hFUckhD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in the code.

The first one is what @umar-hayat mentioned above -> you are unmarshalling into the `data` object and you should be aiming at the `data.M` field.

The second problem is that your JSON's structure doesn't match your struct's structure. Your `Person` has a single field called `M`. If we want to represent this as JSON it would look like this:

```
{
  "M": {
    "Name": "Joe",
    "Body": "Hi",
    "time": 2600
  }
}
```

Instead, you have a field called `person` in your JSON which cannot be matched to any field in your struct. The fact that it's similar to the name of the struct's type doesn't help in any way, I'm afraid.

So, you can either change your JSON and your target:

```
    body := []byte(`{"Name":"Alice","Body":"Hello","Time":1294706395881547000}`)

    var data Person
    err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data.M)
```

Or just your JSON:

```
    body := []byte(`{"M":{"Name":"Alice","Body":"Hello","Time":1294706395881547000}}`)

    var data Person
    err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
```

But it's essential that the names of the fields in your JSON match the names of the fields in your struct. Or, as mentioned by Konstantinos, you can use tags in order to specify particular names with which your struct's fields will be represented in the JSON.

You might find this helpful: https://gobyexample.com/json

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to Unmarshel JSON to the struct. you can check it on Go Playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/nHJaGdbkaxO):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)
type Message struct {
    Name string
    Body string
    Time int64
}

type Person struct {
    M Message
}

func get_content() {

    body := []byte(`{"Name":"Alice","Body":"Hello","Time":1294706395881547000}`)

    var data Person

    err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data.M)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf(data.M.Name)

}

func main() {
    get_content()
}
```

Replace `data` with `data.M` in below line.

`err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data)`

Comment: Hey, Thanks for answering. It works for me when I don't add the tag "person". But doesn't work when json includes for example:   body := []byte(`{"person":{"Name":"Alice","Body":"Hello","Time":1294706395881547000}}`)

Comment: Feel free to accept it as an answer if it is working perfectly for you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as you intent to map Json keys on structs whose fields have different names you should add tags:

```
    type Message struct {
        Name string `json:"Name"`
        Body string `json:"Body"`
        Time int64  `json:"Time"`
    }

    type Person struct {
        M Message `json:"person"`
    }
```

You can find more information [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)

In addition [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go) answer explains in an nutshell the purpose of tags in go.

Comment: He wants to parse a JSON and unmarshal to the struct, not vice versa.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous, I am actually answering the fact why the sample code is not printing the Name.

Comment: cause in this line `err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data)`, the `data`  should be replaced with `data.M` as `Message` is declared as `M` struct within `data`.

Comment: Adding tags only helps you specify new names for the fields in the JSON form. The tags you listed in the Message struct are redundant. And the tag in the Person struct, while it definitely works around the issues, doesn't really address the main problem - the fact that his JSON fields don't match the fields of the struct. It would be significantly better, IMO, to address the core issue, which is that he hasn't completely understood the way we match struct fields to JSON fields. Regarding tags - they are completely optional and you can skip them. Example code: play.golang.org/p/q7PXV5T2o3m