# Unmarshal json file with a map structure

Tags: json, go

I am trying to Unmarshal a file that was encoded with the `json.Marshal()` function. That file is indexed with strings:

#### json test file

```golang
$ cat /tmp/test.json 
{
   "Accentor atrogularis": {
     "CdNom": "3993",
     "NomSci": "Accentor atrogularis",
     "NomVern": "Accenteur à gorge noire",
     "CdStatut": "",
     "Prot": null
   },
   "Accipiter bicolor": {
     "CdNom": "441604",
     "NomSci": "Accipiter bicolor",
     "NomVern": "Epervier bicolore",
     "CdStatut": "IBO2",
     "Prot": [
       "LRM",
       "BONN"
     ]
   }
}
```

#### attempt to decode with Go:

```golang
// Birds bird struct
type Birds struct {
    // CdRef   string
    CdNom    string
    NomSci   string
    NomVern  string
    CdStatut string
    Prot     []string
}

func main() {

    file = "/tmp/test.json"
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }

    var birds Birds

    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &birds)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%T\n", birds)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", birds)

}
```

#### output returns empty struct:

```golang
$ go run empty-nomVern.go 
main.Birds
{    []}
```

Comment: Use a `map[string]Birds`

Comment: So, should we take `Accentor atrogularis` and `Accipiter bicolor` as dynamic keys?

Comment: You can but you don't have to, you can also use a plain struct with struct tags specifying the keys. https://play.golang.org/p/_uBaKhF8gFU

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Accentor atrogularis` and `Accipiter bicolor` are fixed keys and you only care about those two, your one option can be keep up with the deterministic approach. You should modify your structs like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type BirdProps struct {
    // CdRef   string
    CdNom    string
    NomSci   string
    NomVern  string
    CdStatut string
    Prot     []string
}

type Birds struct {
    AccentorAtrogularis BirdProps `json:"Accentor atrogularis"`
    AccipiterBicolor    BirdProps `json:"Accipiter bicolor"`
}

func main() {

    file := "/tmp/test.json"
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }

    var birds Birds

    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &birds)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%T\n", birds)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", birds)

}
```

Should return:

```sh
main.Birds
{{3993 Accentor atrogularis Accenteur à gorge noire  []} {441604 Accipiter bicolor Epervier bicolore IBO2 [LRM BONN]}}
```

For more about that struct tags, check this highly-appreciated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10858787/4636715).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It does indeed return what you posted, but I wanted to Unmarshal it into a `map[string]Birds` as suggested by @Marc in a comment above. So obvious that my question has been downvoted!