# Using reflect to access struct field within a struct

Tags: go, struct, reflection, interface

I have the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Model struct {
    A AStruct  `br:"peg"`
}

type AStruct struct {
    ID string
}

type IModel interface {
}

func main() {
    m := Model{AStruct{ID:"123"}}
    var i IModel;
    i = m
    
    v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(m))
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        tag := v.Type().Field(i).Tag.Get("br")
        if tag == "peg" {
            fieldVal := v.Field(i)
            fmt.Println("fieldVal.Kind():", fieldVal.Kind())

            // How do I get it to work with FieldByName("ID") and print 123 once I know the tag has a value "peg"?
        }
    }

    
    fmt.Println("i is", i)
}
```

I want to use `reflect` to print "123" but I can't it to work.

**EDIT**:

I was actually looping through to find a specific tag. So I don't want to do `v.FieldByName("A") directly. But I can do FieldByName("ID") once I get a handle of` A`.

[The go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DYmUTp6NEp9)

**EDIT 2**:
Change the code to include the tag.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use reflect here? Can you not use type assertion `fmt.Println("i is", i.(Model).A.ID)` (type assertion needs to be done)?

Comment: "How do I get it to work with FieldByName("ID") and print 123?" You simply cannot. Your  `i` contains a copy of `m`. Modifying `m` (in any way) will never change what is stored in `i` .

Comment: @Volker I only need to fetch the value, not intending to modify though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
fmt.Println("field value", v.FieldByName("A").FieldByName("ID"))
```

will do, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IROKM78s82G).

`v` is a `reflect.Value` wrapping a value of type `Model` which has a sturct field `A` which has a struct field `ID`.

**Edit:**

If you want to find a field by tag, see this answer: [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

For the code in your question, this is now it would look like:

```
v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(i))
t := v.Type()
for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
    fieldVal := v.Field(i)
    fmt.Println("fieldVal.Kind():", fieldVal.Kind())
    if t.Field(i).Tag.Get("br") == "peg" {
        fmt.Println("\thas tag: gr=peg")
        fmt.Printf("\tfield value: %+v\n", fieldVal)
        fmt.Println("\tID field value:", fieldVal.FieldByName("ID"))
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aeKj3Qly0Qj)):

```
fieldVal.Kind(): struct
    has tag: gr=peg
    field value: {ID:123}
    ID field value: 123
```

Comment: Sorry I realized I didn't phrase my question clearly. I can't actually do `FieldByName("A")` as I actually loop to check the tag first to see if that's the one I want.

Comment: @huggie There are no tags on the `Model.A` field. Please clarify your question.

Comment: OK I have just made another edit to the code.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: I've read the law of reflection and have been using `reflect` for quite some time, yet I am still very much struggling to use it. It feels like trial and error for me. Do you happen have any recommended resources or ways I can educate myself on this subject?