# Initializing a variable in a struct while declaring a custom json name returns syntax error: unexpected literal

Tags: json, go, struct, initialization

I want to declare a variable inside a struct, initialize it and at the same time declare a custom json name for it. However the compiler always returns a syntax error.

It is possible to initialize the value during struct declaration for instance

```
type Person struct {
        CategoryId     string "Generic"    
        Name           string     `json:"name"`
        Surname        string     `json:"surname"`
    }
```

It is possible to declare a custom json name.

```
type Person struct {
        CategoryId     string  `json:"category_id"`    
        Name           string     `json:"name"`
        Surname        string     `json:"surname"`
    }
```

However the following code returns an error

```
type Person struct {
    CategoryId     string "Generic"  `json:"category_id"`    
    Name           string     `json:"name"`
    Surname        string     `json:"surname"`
}
```

The error returned is the following

> syntax error: unexpected literal `json:"category_id"`, expecting
> semicolon or newline or }

What is the correct syntax?
I tried several combinations like the following:

```
type Person struct {
    CategoryId     string "Generic"  `json:"category_id"`;  
    Name           string     `json:"name"`
    Surname        string     `json:"surname"`
}

type Person struct {
    CategoryId     string "Generic";  `json:"category_id"`
    Name           string     `json:"name"`
    Surname        string     `json:"surname"`
}
```

But none of the above is the correct syntax. I would also appreciate a link to where I can read more about this syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This field declaration:

```
CategoryId     string "Generic"
```

Is **not** initialization (you can't specify default values for fields in Go in the type declaration). The string literal `"Generic"` at the end is the field's tag value. It's the same as this:

```
CategoryId     string `Generic`
```

It doesn't matter if you use a raw or interpreted [string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals), you may only provide a single literal there and it will be the field's tag.

If you want to provide multiple tag values for a single field, by convention you have to separate them with a space, in a single literal, e.g.:

```
CategoryId     string `Generic json:"category_id"`
```

The syntax is detailed in [Spec: Struct types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types):

> A field declaration may be followed by an optional string literal *tag*, which becomes an attribute for all the fields in the corresponding field declaration. An empty tag string is equivalent to an absent tag. The tags are made visible through a [reflection interface](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag) and take part in [type identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) for structs but are otherwise ignored.

For an overview, more details and convention, I highly recommend to read this related question: [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)