# Get struct Tag with reflection - Error: type reflect.Value has no field or method Tag

Tags: go, struct, reflection, introspection

Let's say we have this [PoC](https://play.golang.org/p/dUrDg0i_Lxc):

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "reflect"
        "strings"
)

type MyStruct struct {
        Str string `gorm:"size:10" json:"string"`
}

func main() {
        aStruct := MyStruct{"Hello"}

        s := reflect.ValueOf(&aStruct).Elem()
        if s.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
                        field := s.Field(i)
                        if field.IsValid() {
                                if field.CanSet() {
                                        fmt.Printf("%T\n", field)  // reflect.Value, need reflect.StructField
                                        gormTag := field.Tag.Get("gorm")  // Compile ERROR HERE
                                        gormSize := strings.Split(gormTag, "size:")[1]
                                        fmt.Println(gormSize)
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

The error is:

```
go run test1.go 
# command-line-arguments
./test1.go:22:22: field.Tag undefined (type reflect.Value has no field or method Tag)
```

Tested with go 1.14.6 and go 1.15.2.

In my understanding I need to cast (or get from) `reflect.Value` to `reflect.StructField`
Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags belong to the *type* of fields of the struct, not to the *values* of the struct type.

[`reflect.ValueOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf) returns you the wrapper of the *value*, not its type. To get the tag value, you need to start from the wrapper of the type, e.g. acquired with [`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf):

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(&aStruct).Elem()
```

And the type wrapper of the field in the loop (which will be of type [`reflect.StructTag`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructField)):

```
field := s.Field(i)
fieldt := t.Field(i)
```

And use `fieldt` to get the tag:

```
gormTag := fieldt.Tag.Get("gorm") // No error, this works
```

With this addition, output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/y4QluzpNhJv)):

```
reflect.Value
10
```

See related: [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)