# Recursively parse over struct from dict keys

Tags: go

I am trying to recursively parse a form data dictionary into an embedded struct.
It is *kindof* working, but eventually only one field gets set. I figured that the field keeps being overridden by the old struct, but need some help finding the solution.

Entrypoint of the function:

```golang
func FormDataToStruct(data map[string]string, s any) {
    // Parse the form data into the struct
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        v = v.Elem()
    }
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        panic("not a struct")
    }
    formParse(data, v, s)
}
```

Set the values on the topmost struct:

```golang
func formParse(data map[string]string, v reflect.Value, s any) {
    for key, value := range data {
        if hasField(v, key) {
            println("Found field: " + key)
            var val, err = TransformValue(s, key, value)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            SetValue(s, key, val)
            delete(data, key)
        }
    }
    // Set values of inner structs
    for key, value := range data {
        keys := strings.Split(key, "_")
        // Parse the inner struct recursively with another function
        recurseKeys(keys, value, v, s, s)
    }
}
```

Struct looks like this:

```
    type Me struct {
        Name string
        Age  int
        Friend struct {
            Name string
            Age  int
        }
    }
```

Form data to parse looks like this:

```
map[name:John age:20 friend_name:Jane friend_age:20]
```

```golang
func recurseKeys(keys []string, value string, v reflect.Value, s any, parent any) {
    if len(keys) == 1 {
        // We are at the end of the keys
        // Set the value
        var val, err = TransformValue(s, keys[0], value)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        SetValue(s, keys[0], val)
        return
    }
    // We are not at the end of the keys
    // We need to iterate over the struct
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        if strings.EqualFold(v.Type().Field(i).Name, keys[0]) {
            // We found the field
            // Recurse with the next key
            newS := reflect.New(v.Field(i).Type())
            recurseKeys(keys[1:], value, v.Field(i), newS.Interface(), parent)
            // Check if the field on the old struct is a pointer, if it is, we need to set the pointer
            // If it is not a pointer, we need to set the value
            if v.Field(i).Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                // Check if newS is a pointer
                if newS.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                    v.Field(i).Set(newS)
                } else {
                    v.Field(i).Set(newS.Elem())
                }
            } else {
                // Check if newS is a pointer
                if newS.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                    v.Field(i).Set(newS.Elem())
                } else {
                    v.Field(i).Set(newS)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above form data through the struct would result in the following output:

```golang
println(meInstance)
// {John 20 {Jane 0}}
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

*EDIT*

Go playground with minimal reproducible example:
https://go.dev/play/p/d5pIK3uQrUL

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this code is that it creates a new struct and replaces it with the existing object. Therefore, you will always see the last assigned value.

The fixed version of the code will be like below:

```golang
func recurseKeys(keys []string, value string, v reflect.Value, s any, parent any) {
    if len(keys) == 1 {
        // We are at the end of the keys
        // Set the value
        var val, err = TransformValue(s, keys[0], value)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        SetValue(s, keys[0], val)
        return
    }
    // We are not at the end of the keys
    // We need to iterate over the struct
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        if strings.EqualFold(v.Type().Field(i).Name, keys[0]) {
            // We found the field
            // Recurse with the next key
            if v.Field(i).IsZero() {
                var newS reflect.Value
                if v.Field(i).Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                    newS = reflect.New(v.Field(i).Type().Elem()).Elem()
                } else {
                    newS = reflect.New(v.Field(i).Type())
                }

                // Check if the field on the old struct is a pointer, if it is, we need to set the pointer
                // If it is not a pointer, we need to set the value
                if v.Field(i).Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                    v.Field(i).Set(newS.Addr())
                } else {
                    v.Field(i).Set(newS.Elem())
                }

            }
            if v.Field(i).Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                recurseKeys(keys[1:], value, v.Field(i), v.Field(i).Interface(), parent)
            } else {
                recurseKeys(keys[1:], value, v.Field(i), v.Field(i).Addr().Interface(), parent)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This code accepts struct pointers as well.

Performance improvement tip: You may want to consider scanning the target object and creating a map of `name -> Reflect value` to reduce the number of loops.

Maintenance tip: It's better to consider using [struct tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-struct-tags-in-go) instead of reflecting the struct Variable name directly.

Comment: Yes! Perfect. I figured it had something to do with replacing the  current struct, but just couldn't hack it. Thank you for the tips too!